# Plot points in 3D in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I need to plot points in 3D in MATLAB. For example, look at this image:

[image]

The background represents a plane, and the color of each
point is dependent on its Z value. It is a 2D plot,
but if you plot this in 3D you should get a plane and points.
I did not create this image, and I wonder how to plot like this.
I need to make the colors of the points dependent on their Z value and
plot in 2D, or if I plot this in 3D how do I plot points in 3D?

THanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `scatter3`

```
scatter3(x, y, z, 'ob');
```

See doc [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html).

Comment: Thank you! Very nice function.